# Accesing HTML pages on safari

Tags: javascript, android, html, safari, bonjour

I am facing a issue when trying to view the HTML page in **Safari Browser** 
Web page is hosted on my Android device.
But when trying to view Web page in Firefox and IE no problem is coming(Everything is working as expected)
After debugging in Safari i found that Web page was not loaded completely.So on decreasing the length of file and by removing extra spaces and comments(reducing the character count), it started working perfectly.
Still not sure why this is happening.
Has any one else also faced this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when you copy and paste text, you copy by mistake special characters that are represented like whitespaces but behave differently. These special characters often cause trouble (for example extra line breaks or errors). I think this might be your problem too.

As a piece of advice, I always configure my text editor to represent whitespaces, tabulations... in order to avoid that problem.

Comment: In that case the HTML file should also not work in Firefox or IE.